# Birt charts doesn't appear in google chrome or Microsoft Edge

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, charts, birt, microsoft-edge

I'm [birt libraries](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/)
to generate charts, they show properly in Mozilla Firefox , bu they don't show up either in Google chrome or Microsoft Edge. Does anybody know how can I make these charts appear just as in Firefox?

In Firefox:
[image]

In Chrome:
[image]

Comment: It looks like a wrong mime type sent by the server application, or something like that. Actually it works if reports are displayed from the Eclipse WebViewer, so the problem is specific to your context. Without further information  i don't believe someone will be able to help. Chrome console / development tools should probably help to find out the root cause of the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually because we are using [sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home) framework in our project. The sitemesh filter has modified the response and the solution was to exclude the BirtEngineServlet which has the responsibility to view the charts from being manipulated with that filter.